# Why svg morphing won't work

Tags: animation, svg

I've got problem with svg animation, it's simply won't work.
I've done everything with the internet tutorials including the same number of points for two shapes. But instead of animation, it's just changing one shape to another. Here is my code:

```
<path fill="#1EB287">
<animate 
         attributeName="d" 
         dur="3000ms" 
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         values="M12.193,44.64c-0.004-0.278,0.049-0.563,0.16-0.854c0.11-0.29,0.266-0.563,0.468-0.817
c0.092-0.115,0.191-0.224,0.299-0.327c0.13-0.125,0.271-0.242,0.424-0.35c0.19-0.132,0.392-0.244,0.606-0.333
c0.101-0.042,0.204-0.08,0.31-0.112c0.289-0.088,0.559-0.066,0.812,0.063c0.084,0.043,0.167,0.099,0.248,0.166
c0.06,0.05,0.118,0.106,0.172,0.166c0.112,0.123,0.213,0.266,0.302,0.43c0.1,0.184,0.186,0.392,0.257,0.626
c0.045,0.147,0.081,0.318,0.107,0.512c0.043,0.313,0.063,0.687,0.058,1.121c-0.003,0.326-0.101,1.924-0.15,2.409
c-0.027,0.263-0.057,0.533-0.09,0.809c-0.05,0.417-0.108,0.848-0.173,1.293c-0.04,0.274-0.083,0.553-0.128,0.838
c-0.092,0.577-0.188,1.159-0.288,1.748c-0.083,0.49-0.169,0.984-0.259,1.483c-0.196,1.101-0.4,2.193-0.612,3.279L12.193,44.64z;

                 M137.262,49.477c-0.019-0.148-0.231-0.264-0.231-1.14c0-1.983,1.124-3.321,2.925-3.801l-0.545,2.181
c-0.692,2.793-1.354,5.106-1.354,6.743c0,1.669,0.81,2.627,3.188,2.627c1.91,0,3.091-0.606,3.934-1.876
c0.39-0.588,0.706-1.32,0.986-2.199c0.294-0.918,0.553-1.998,0.814-3.245l0.715-3.38l0.375-1.775h-2.33l-0.729,3.367l-0.377,1.74
c-0.451,2.078-0.819,3.408-1.184,4.258c-0.58,1.361-1.144,1.493-2.008,1.493c-0.826,0-1.14-0.545-1.14-1.487
c0-0.694,0.173-1.599,0.539-3.042c0.364-1.443,0.923-3.427,1.689-6.278c-0.347-0.066-0.512-0.083-0.793-0.083
c-3.206,0-6.247,2.049-6.247,4.379C135.494,49.064,136.173,49.477,137.262,49.477z;"/>
```

Comment: The values need to have the same number and types of arguments. Do they?

Comment: How to check this? I've exported it from illustrator with the same amount of points.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the same order and type of drawing commands in each. That is why it can't animate. Just count the number of lowercase "c"s as a start. The first path has 17, the second has 14. There's an uppercase C in your second path in the last line that has no matching command in the first path. And there's an uppercase L in your first path at the end with no matching command in the second path.

Please read some SVG tutorials before you post on this again. This is your second post on this problem.

Comment: Case doesn't matter (at least not on Firefox). C and c count as the same.

Comment: But how to make sure the drawing are the same order and type? I've exported both paths from illustrator with the same amount of points.

Comment: That sounds like a great but separate question that I'm sure you could ask on StackOverflow

Comment: Unfortunetly i can't... i've reached the question limit :(